# Pass class variables onto a class on another script in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a class variable on another class in on another script, but I'm not sure how that's possible. I've seen how to use methods or functions, but not variables.

For example something like this

```
#old.py

class Sassy:

    bbq = "nice"

    lol = "funny"

    def DoesNothing(self):

        #this is the method's body and nothing really goes here
```

How can I use `bbq` and `lol` on a new script?

Is this the right way?

```
#new.py

from old import *

class HeySexy:

    new = Sassy()

    def ShowMeThatString(self):

        print(self.new.bbq)
```

Comment: I hope this is just a quick example of a class and not something you're trying to implement...

Comment: Relax, just an example lol

Comment: changed the question a bit. Sorry! lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's almost right.

Never do this:

```
from old import *
```

Instead do this:

```
from old import Sassy

new = Sassy()
print(new.bbq)
```

Comment: @satoru is right that since ``bbq`` is a class variable, you can access it without creating a Sassy instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and since they are class variables, you can also do `Sassy.bbq`.

PS: As tsroten told you, `import *` is considered bad practice, because it'll make it difficult to find out where an object came from once your module become larger. You can read [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) if you want to learn more about Python coding style.